# Why is my Google Cloud Functions directory blank even when I follow the steps to initialize one?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use Google Cloud Functions using Firebase to listen for changes in Google Cloud Firestore. The setup process is really frustrating me because I not familiar with Node.js or Firebase CLI. I decided to follow [this tutorial](https://fireship.io/courses/cloud-functions/intro-setting-up-firebase-cloud-functions/), however, even when I follow the steps, my project directory in VS Code never fills up with the necessary files like package.json.

I have tried to create directories with different names to see if I can start over, but the same issue is occurring with all of my directories that I create.

This is how I attempted to setup Cloud Functions:

First in iTerm 2 (command-line):

```
$ npm install firebase-tools -g
$ mkdir myproject
$ firebase login
$ firebase init
```

When I initialize Firebase, this happens:

```
You're about to initialize a Firebase project in this directory:

/Users/michaelderiso <- That seems odd because it probably should be pointing to my project directory...

Before we get started, keep in mind:

 * You are initializing in an existing Firebase project directory

? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this 
folder? Press Space
 to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. (Press 
<space> to select, <a> to toggle all, <i> to invert selection)
 ◯ Database: Deploy Firebase Realtime Database Rules
 ◯ Firestore: Deploy rules and create indexes for Firestore
❯◯ Functions: Configure and deploy Cloud Functions
 ◯ Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
 ◯ Storage: Deploy Cloud Storage security rules
```

I select Functions and then select TypeScript, then it asks if I want to overwrite files I previously installed!

After I complete init, I open my project directory in VS Code, but nothing is in the directory, it's just an empty folder.

I expected the directory to fill up with the files that `firebase init` should create, like package.json, but nothing is there. Why is my directory not filling up with the files that `firebase init` should create and how can I fix this issue?

UPDATE:

I have just checked and it turns out that it is installing Functions into my home directory. I can access the files, but shouldn't it be in a different directory? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must `cd` into the newly made directory `myproject` in order for firebase init to happen in the right place.

Please try:

```
$ npm install firebase-tools -g
$ mkdir myproject
$ cd myproject
$ firebase login
$ firebase init
```

Comment: It still does not work. When I do `code .` to open the directory, the folder is just empty.

Comment: Wait, nevermind. I just went into my home directory and deleted the node_modules and the other files Firebase downloaded. That let me start over and fix the error I had. It is working now!

Comment: Great, happy that you found a solution

Answer (score -1):

Happened same for me.

1. I switched to my home directory i.e. *C:/Users/{my_user_name}*
2. Sorted the files based on "Date Modified"
3. Copied all the required files to my required directory
4. Closed the bash/cmd
5. Opened [code .] again at required directory
6. Files are all visible there in vs code.

P.S. Run the command to update node/npm module to the latest version

Comment: Please do not add comments/suggestions/opinions as answers. This makes it harder to navigate through answers to find a working solution.